# Which electrode potentials govern Lithium-ion batteries?

Tags: chemical-potential, electrochemistry

I have a very basic question on why Li+ ions move from anode to cathode during discharge of lithium-ion batteries. Others have asked, but the explanations don't give electrode potentials.

1. what electrode potentials drive an LIB? The potential of Li+ v graphite, and Li+ v LiCoO2 (to take one cathode chemistry) or Li+ v the electrolyte?
2. ions will move from high to low potential, but the potential of LiC6 is 0.1 V vs. Li/Li+ (https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.202208743) but Li+ v LiCoO2 is about 4v. So why do the ions appear to move from low to high instead of high to low?

[image: Energy of Li vs electrolyte HOMO and LUMO]

I am asking what drives the movement from anode to cathode, electrochemically..with numbers and potentials please. Thank you in advance.

[[image: Li+ Potentials]][2